# Nothing being displayed in place of AngularJS expression

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, json

I am trying to fetch data from mysql using php and trying to pass the data in json format to angularjs so that I can display data in table.

HTML code is:

```
<body ng-app="myModule">
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
             <div ng-controller="myController">
              <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>email</th>
                        <th>id</th>
                        <th>name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees"></tr>
                    <td>{{employee.username}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
                </tbody>
              </table>
             </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->

</div>
```

AngularJS code is:

```
var app = angular
        .module("myModule", [])
        .controller("myController", function ($scope,$http) {
            $http.post('http://enrolin.in/test/login.php')
                 .then(function(response){
                    $scope.employees=response.data;
                 }); });
```

Working php link that outputs json is : http://enrolin.in/test/login.php
Working link of table is http://enrolin.in/test/

**But when I try to load the html. It does not load any data from the database.**

[image: I tried to view it in console, looks like ng-repeat is repeated 6 times that is exactly the number of rows in database that means data is imported but is not being displayed somehow]

I tried to view it in console, looks like ng-repeat is repeated 6 times that is exactly the number of rows in database that means data is imported but is not being displayed somehow

Comment: I noticed you are sending a `text/html` header with that response. I would suggest changing that to `application/json`. Also, have you tried putting a console.log inside that response handler? Are you sure you ever reach that function? (PS: should you really be posting what appear to be emails and names here?)

Comment: Those emails and names are not real. Thanks Pevara for replying. Can you please guide me on how to change the header to application/json.

Comment: Google is your friend. Example #1 from the official docs for `header` should point you in the right direction: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#example-5007

Comment: Just added header('Content-Type: application/json'); to my php but still not working.

Comment: Can you try `$scope.employees=response;`? Leave out the `.data`

Comment: It looks like your response is a list of objects. I believe you should be able to access the fields the way you are if `$scope.employees=response`.

Comment: Hello mhatch, just tried your removing it. Still not working.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot test the app because of CORS access. If you provide `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` temporarily I will test it.

Comment: I have allowed the cross-site access.

Comment: You have just to JSON.parse() your response.data cause you respond some text. Text is different from JSON. So you have to parse your text into json

Comment: Angular parses JSON automatically. Also, the actually response body is actually inside `response.data`. There is nothing wrong with that js code.

Comment: Hi  Romain De Sa Jardim can you please guide me how to do that. I am new to angularJS and JS.

Comment: The 2 answers below are correct. It was an HTML error.

Comment: Thankyou guys, seems like the problem was in HTML :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in your HTML.

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in employees"></tr>
    <td>{{employee.username}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.id}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
```

The `<td>` are outside the `<tr>`, so `{{ employee }}` does not exist in the `<td>`.

This should work :

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
    <td>{{employee.username}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.id}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Yes, It worked. This little issue had me on my toes since last 4 hours. Thanks Jean :)

Answer (score 4):

It is just a silly mistake in your view (can't believe I overlooked it at first).

You are just repeating empty rows now:

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees"></tr>
  <td>{{employee.username}}</td>
  <td>{{employee.id}}</td>
  <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
</tbody>
```

Those `td`s obviously need to be inside the repeated row:

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
    <td>{{employee.username}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.id}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Yes, It worked. This little issue had me on my toes since last 4 hours. Thanks Pevara:)